# An expression like newton's binomial

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I have the following sum, it looks just like Newton's Binomial the only difference is that it's twice the sum,

> I have $$ \sum_0^{n} \left( \begin{matrix} 2n \\ 2k \end{matrix} \right) a ^{2k} b^{2n - 2k}$$
>   and I want to express this with $(a+b)^n$ or something in that sort. Is there a way to do it?

how do I turn this into Newton's binomial, it's so close but so far away. Is there some sort of manipulation im missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the binomial theorem to expand
$$
\frac12\left((a+b)^{2n} + (a-b)^{2n}\right)
$$
and then simplify terms of equal degree in $a$ and $b$ will give you the sum you seek.

Comment: How did you get to it? So I could use that solution for my next time

Comment: @Guysudai1 Experience from playing around with tricks like this. There is no simple trick one can learn to get them all. It's just a large collection of simple tricks that you can try each time and hopefully they work.

Comment: I mean, do you just play around and try different things? Or do you try to express the sum differently ?

Comment: @Guysudai1 Mostly yes. This exact one I've seen a few times before, so I didn't have to work a lot, but trial and error is what I usually do with problems like this.

Comment: Ok thanks for the solution.